# Presenting UIViewController in IOS using cocos2d-JS

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x

I want to present a view controller on top of the current view controller and I am using cocos2d-JS. After reading for a while I came to know there is only one view controller inside cocos-2d and everything happens through this one controller only.

I am trying to present view controller using this command

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but apparently Xcode is not able to locate CCDirector class. When i try to incude CCDirector.h as a header file then i start getting error as "stack file not found" .

I think I am not able to include CCDirector properly.. what is the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

use [[RootViewController sharedRootViewController] presentViewController:]

or get window from class AppController, add [window addSubView]

just look at AppController.cpp, cocos2d viewController is constructed and added there

Comment: Hey thanks :). This really helped. thanks once again